# PHP Creating a request in code

Tags: php, httprequest

I need to create a new PHP HTTP Request within my code. It returns a json-encoded array of data. How do I create a new HTTP Request and not redirect to that location?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you please clarify what you are trying to do better.

Comment: You're probably looking for `fopen($url);` or similar, but without more details it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to generate a post to run a php script that will return you some data ( in json format ) so you can use it in the page that caused the POST to happen? If so read up on AJAX and to make life easier also look up jQuery ( a javascript framework)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're trying to get a json file and put it into an array:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/test.json');
$json_array = json_decode($content);
print_r($json_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: http://codular.com/curl-with-php

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://stackoverflow.com'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);


//For testing only
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($resp);die();
```